# Can we enforce inheritence after super class objects have been individually created? ObjA obj = new ObjB();

Tags: java, inheritance

Is there a way to enforce inheritance between objects after they have been created Individually? Consider the example given below

```
    class Test{        
        class publisher{
            public String pubName;
            //10-15 other members here
            public String getPublisher(){
                return pubName;
            }
            public void setName(String name){
                pubName = name;
            }
        }
        class author extends publisher{
            public String authorName;
            //5-10 other members here
            public String getAuthor(){
                return authorName;
            }
            @Override
            public void setName(String name){
                authorName = name;
            }
        }
        public static void main(String Args[]){
            publisher pub1 = new publisher();
            pub1.setName("Amanda Book House");

            //I want to do something like this below?
            pub1 auth1 = new author();
            //I want to create an author who has inherited information from pub1 
            //so auth1.getPublisher() should give me Amanda Book House 

        }
    }
```

So to be specific I want to know if while creating a derived class object, there is a way to inherit information from a base class object that's already been created. I know that when a derived object is created, an implicit call is made to super class constructor. How does that come into the picture for this case?

Comment: Inheritance is for **is a** associations: an Apple **is a** Fruit, a List **is a** Collection. An author **is not a** publisher. So inheritance is not the right choice here. You have a **has a** association: an author **has a** publisher. So Author should have a field of type Publisher. It shouldn't extend Publisher. `Author newAuthor = new Author(pub1);`. Also, please, respect the Java naming conventions: classes start wth an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that. What you can do instead is ensure that the base classes (`Publisher` in your case) have *copy constructors*, so that you can pass in a `Publisher` instance to the `Author` constructor to *copy* its state into the object being constructed:

```
class Publisher {
    private String pubName;
    public Publisher(Publisher other) { // ***
        this.pubName = other.pubName;   // ***
    }                                   // ***
    //10-15 other members here
    public String getPublisher(){
        return pubName;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        pubName = name;
    }
}

class Author extends Publisher{
    private String authorName;
    public Author(Publisher pub) {      // ***
        super(pub);                     // ***
    }                                   // ***
    //5-10 other members here
    public String getAuthor(){
        return authorName;
    }
    @Override
    public void setName(String name){
        authorName = name;
    }
}
```

So then:

```
Publisher pub1 = new publisher();
pub1.setName("Amanda Book House");
Author auth1 = new Author(pub1);        // *** *Copies* the state from pub1
```

It's important to note that this makes a *copy*; if you change the state of `pub1` later (for instance, change the name), it won't have any effect on `auth1`'s state.

---

Side note: You can obviously do what you like in your own code, but when asking for help, please follow standard Java naming conventions, it's important for making your code readable to others.

Side note 2: If you have accessors for something (like `pubName`), the instance variable holding it should be private.

I've done both of those things in the above.